# Git - Invalid path on Windows from a repo created in OSX

Tags: git

I have cloned a repo from a project that was initially made on OSX. I'm using Windows.

When I checked out to a previous commit, I got this in status:

```
deleted:    Data/Levels/Pack03 - Forest /03_25_BossGate3.json
```

This file doesn't exist in the latest commit, but it existed in the previous commit, and I think git wasn't able to create it because of the invalid path "Pack 03 - Forest " (name with space character in the end), and that's why I see it as deleted in status.

How can I fix this? I need the deleted files, and I wouldn't like to manually fix each file that may have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the repo in a virutal machine running a UNIX os and then copy it over to Windows?
Not sure if it would work but worth a try.